# Good practice to link script on a page getting loaded by ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page called `index.php` and on this page I have a form that takes a number and processes the form via ajax and returns the result on this same page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Ordertrack</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.css' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/print.css' media="print" />
</head>
<body>
    <form action="processing.php" id="submitsearch" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="ordernum" value="">
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
<div id="searchresults"></div>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/example.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see I am linking my css and js in `index.php` and a few things were not working in jquery when I was submitting the form as it was getting to `processing.php` so, I changed click to onclick but then I wanted to check on a few things like a link with a class `delete` exists and that wasn't working. Then I added the script to `processing.php`. Now I need to know if this is good or bad. Should I link my js and css files in `processing.php` ?

This is the ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submitsearch').submit(function() { 
        $.ajax({ 
            data: $(this).serialize(), 
            type: $(this).attr('method'), 
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            success: function(response) { 
                $('#searchresults').html(response);
                $('#submitsearch').hide();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

This is my `processing.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Ordertrack</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
      <div id="page-wrap">

    <div style="clear:both"></div>

    <div id="customer">

    </div>
    <div class="border-rtlt"></div>

    <div class="border-rtlt"></div>
    <table id="items">

      <tr>
          <th>Products</th>
          <th>SKU</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Qty</th>
          <th>Discount</th>
          <th>Subtotal</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="item-row">
          <td class="description"><div class="delete-wpr"><textarea>data</textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td>
          <td><textarea>data</textarea></td>
          <td><textarea class="cost">data</textarea></td>
          <td><textarea class="qty">data</textarea></td>
          <td><span>data</span></td>
          <td><span class="price">data</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="hiderow">
        <td colspan="6"><a id="addrow" href="javascript:;" title="Add a row">Add a row</a></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
          <td colspan="3" class="blank"> </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Subtotal</td>
          <td class="total-value"><div id="subtotal">data</div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>

          <td colspan="3" class="blank"> </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Total</td>
          <td class="total-value"><div id="total">data</div></td>
      </tr>

    </table>

  </div>
  <script>
     if ($(".item-row").length == 1) {
      $("a.delete").hide();
    };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Regardless of your question, I do recommend putting the call to the jQuery script in the header and not in the body.

Comment: I managed to make your code work without anything special added.... Are you sure your jQuery is legit ?
You can look at it here
http://aviadclicktale.co.nf/StackOverflow/

Comment: The code is working what I am trying to explain is this part of code 'if ($(".item-row").length == 1) {$("a.delete").hide();};' does not work if I put it in 'example.js'. I call this 'example.js' in 'index.php' and not in 'processing.php'

Comment: Oh, ok now I get your question.
Your code - the one that removes the row - is executed BEFORE the actual table/rows are added to the DOM, therefor once the ajax return the page the script was already executed and won't be executed again.
A good practice for that (Or just a simple solution )will be to call this code from the 'success' part @ the ajax call AFTER the .html(response) is executed, or via some change listeners.
Is this answering your question ?

Comment: So I should not link example.js in processing.php right? This is bad practice and what are change listeners? Any reference?

Comment: Yes you are right, as it will be bad practice. Im currently on a train so i can not reference you at the moment, but you should Google some like ''DOM change listener' or so

Comment: Sorry I got this all wrong. I have some other script that I want to run like the above checking delete link. Can I link that other script in processing.php?

Comment: You give out your answer and i'll accept it and thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your button

```
 <input type="submit" id='btnSubmit'/>
```

You only need to prevent the default behavior of the button

```
$( "#btnSubmit'" ).click(function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({ 
        data: $( "#submitsearch'").serialize(), 
        type: $("#submitsearch'").attr('method'), 
        url: $("#submitsearch'").attr('action'),
        success: function(response) { 
            $('#searchresults').html(response);
            $('#submitsearch').hide();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. I even tried with submit.

Comment: i have edited my answer. please check if it solve your problem.

Comment: your code submits the form and processes it to processing.php but as I said I want to check a link on processing.php if it exists do something. When I add this checking script to processing.php then it works fine. This is a link on processing.php <a class="delete">delete</a>

Comment: I just want to know what is a good practice my code works fine.

Comment: that is a bad practice. you should not put a js and css on your ajax. you can check if something exists on client side before submitting an ajax request